# JQuery - get contents of certain divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am cloning a form, and it gives me a lot of data I don't want.  I am already doing the following which helps

```
var formDataUnformatted = $("#content").html();
var cleanFormData = formDataUnformatted.replace(/\t/, "").replace(/ ui-draggable| element/gi, "").replace(/<div class="close">.<\/div>/g, "").replace(/ data-(.+)="(.+)"/g, "");
```

This still leaves me with a lot of stuff however.  Now I can see myself doing many replace calls to clean everything up, which does not seem that good.  The above leaves me with something like the following (but I have removed a lot of code which is not really necessary).

```
<input style="" class="ui-sortable-handle" name="_token" value="sdfsd" type="hidden">
<div class="tab-pane active ui-sortable-handle" id="editor-tab">
        <fieldset id="content_form_name">
            <legend>Document Name</legend>
        </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="form-group-handle">
    <label for="text_input" class="control-label col-sm-4">Text Input</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-7">
        <input id="text_input" class="form-control" name="text_input" type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group-handle">
    <label for="textareaInput" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Text Area:</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-7">
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="textareaInput" name="textareaInput" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

My aim is to get the divs and contents of any div which has the class form-group-handle.  So essentially, the above should be turned into

```
<div class="form-group-handle">
    <label for="text_input" class="control-label col-sm-4">Text Input</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-7">
        <input id="text_input" class="form-control" name="text_input" type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group-handle">
    <label for="textareaInput" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Text Area:</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-7">
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="textareaInput" name="textareaInput" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Instead of finding all the bad divs, and using something like replace, is there any way to just find all divs with the class I want, and keep that content?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use clone to that specific class:

```
var clone = $('.form-group-handle').clone();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".form-group-handle").each(function() 
{
  console.log($('.form-group-handle').clone());

  // or

  console.log($('<div>').append($('.form-group-handle').clone()).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="" class="ui-sortable-handle" name="_token" value="sdfsd" type="hidden">
<div class="tab-pane active ui-sortable-handle" id="editor-tab">
        <fieldset id="content_form_name">
            <legend>Document Name</legend>
        </fieldset>
</div>

<div class="form-group-handle">
    <label for="text_input" class="control-label col-sm-4">Text Input</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-7">
        <input id="text_input" class="form-control" name="text_input" type="text">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group-handle">
    <label for="textareaInput" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Text Area:</label>
    <div class="controls col-sm-7">
        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" id="textareaInput" name="textareaInput" cols="50"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is, the html content is not in the DOM.  The html is stored within the variable formDataUnformatted.  So how can I clone all .form-group-handle divs within the variable formDataUnformatted?

Comment: Is it possible to do the following:

 (1) **$('.element').append(formDataUnformatted);**
 (2)  **$('.form-group-handle').clone());**
 (3)  **$('.element').html("");**

This would create the elements from the html string and then find them, once found remove.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery with class selector, the jQuery object contains only the divs you need

```
$('div.form-group-handle')
```

But the jQuery object contains a **collection** of DOM elements (you chan check the number of elements matching your selector with $.('div.form-group-handle').length), so you need to iterate through them to build your final string.

If you want the html of each div

```
var formDataUnformatted = '';
$('div.form-group-handle').each(function() {
     formDataUnformatted += this.outerHTML; 
     // where 'this' represents each matching div
});
```

EDIT (regarding your comment to Jordan Lowe answer indicating that html is not in the DOM)

If formDataUnformatted is a string representing html, you can filter that content to get the collection of divs

```
$(formDataUnformatted).filter('div.form-group-handle');
```

Answer (score 1):

With a mixture of a few of these answers, I seem to have found a problem.  Some of the above were through errors because it is not a JQuery Object.  So I came up with the following solution

```
var formDataUnformatted = $("#content").html();
var cleanFormData = formDataUnformatted.replace(/\t/, "").replace(/ ui-draggable| element/gi, "").replace(/<div class="close">.<\/div>/g, "").replace(/ data-(.+)="(.+)"/g, "");

var dataArray = new Array();

$(cleanFormData).filter('div.form-group-handle').each(function() {
    dataArray.push(this.outerHTML);
});
```